# ONVIF OnvifClientDevice execption in c++

Tags: c++, openssl, visual-studio-2019, onvif

I have been trying to use [rapidonvif](https://github.com/linkingvision/rapidonvif) library to get information about my ONVIF IP camera using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 64-bit. I have successfully built the library with Visual Studio 2019 and generated `onvifcpp.lib`. The generated folder looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Hfk.jpg). I couldn't use 64-bit openssl and used `openssl-1.0.1g` from `3rdparty/openssl-1.0.1g` folder in the `rapidonvif` repository.
Anyway, I finally took help from [LeonCam](https://github.com/kazimierczak-robert/LeonCam) and wrote a simple script to generate `OnvifClientDevice` like the script below.

```cpp
#include "ONVIF/onvifclientdevice.hpp" 
#include "ONVIF/onvifclientmedia.hpp"
#include "ONVIF/onvifclientptz.hpp"
int main()//int argc, char** argv)
{
   OnvifClientPTZ* client_ptz;

   string url = "http://192.168.1.116/onvif/device_service";
   string username = "root";
   string password = "root";

   OnvifClientDevice client_device(url, ipaddress, password);
}
```

LeonCam uses [openssl-win 64 bit (LeonCam/openssl-win64)](https://github.com/kazimierczak-robert/LeonCam) and I have used it in my project too. But I see an exception, whenever I run the main script to create the `OnvifClientDevice` object. The exception is [access violation writing location ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mhak.jpg) in [stdsoap2.cpp](https://github.com/linkingvision/rapidonvif/blob/master/gsoap/gsoap/runtime/stdsoap2.cpp). I have checked my IP address with **ONVIF Device Manager** and also successfully could make [ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKOk4.jpg) to the camera from pc. The user name and password is also right. I am not really sure whether it is an internal problem inside my code or I have made mistake while building the ONVIF library. I have searched for the direct build library for the ONVIF which I could just add to my visual studio project, and have tried to use different repositories from GitHub, but either the other repositories use Qt or they build it for Linux distributions. I didn't also find any easy tutorials to follow.

Comment: Ahsan are you successful in running the code? I am also looking for the solution